# Wordpress API- XML-RPC: wp.newPost returns false roughly 40% of the time

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, xml-rpc

The [API documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost) clearly states that the wp.newPost returns the new post id, but roughly 40% of the time we're getting a response of false, but with and HTTP Response Code of 100. The post is published to Wordpress successfully either way.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getXMLRPCURL());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);

// Encode htaccess credentials if they're set
$htaccess_credentials = $this->getHtaccessCredentials();
if ($htaccess_credentials) {
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $htaccess_credentials->toString());
}

$results = curl_exec($ch); // <<-- RETURNS FALSE HERE.
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // Returns 100
curl_close($ch);
return $results;
```

I'm happy to post a sample $request string, but that part seems to be working fine. I was just wondering if anyone has run into this before? It seems to have been run into [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087648/wordpress-xml-rpc-post-to-a-specific-category/12493288#12493288), but with little resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Sheesh. Timeout. Duh. Someone had set the CURL timeout to 1. Nonetheless, we're still not receiving full responses sometimes even without a timeout set - likely the default socket timeout is kicking in. Nonetheless, we have a (somewhat weighty) workaround.

Have a nice day.